What is HP in "Bitcoin Core - HP"?
Just noticed when I run Bitcoin Core, the title bar says "Bitcoin Core - HP". What does HP mean?

Bitcoin Core version v27.0.0
macOS Sonoma 14.5 (23F79)

bitcoin.conf:
server=1  
dbcache=4000 
prune=2000 
datacarriersize=0 
mempoolfullrbf=1


If you have a wallet open, Bitcoin Core displays it as part of the window name.
You probably have a wallet named "HP".
